# How can I make it so the user can input different answers but display the same result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering how I could display the same result if the user inputs two specific answers in the input command (ie 'end' and 'End').

Here's the code I have so far; everything is working except the "end" part:

```
def password(): #defines password
print("Please input your password.")
pass2 = input("Password: ")
if pass2 == ("abcd123"):
    print("Thank you for using Efficient Systems, Co.")
    end = input("Type end to exit: ")
    while True:
        if end == ("end") and ("End"):
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid command.")
            end = input("Type end to exit: ")
else:
    print("Invalid command.")
    time.sleep(1)
    pass2 = input("Password: ")
```

I think it's worth noting that if I do type in 'end', it goes back to pass2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `or`:

```
if end == "end" or end == "End":
    ....
```

if you want to check the string case-insensitive, use [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold):

```
if end.casefold() == "end":
    ...
```

Comment: I attempted if end.casefold == "end": --- but it comes back saying the following error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'casefold'. What could I do?

Comment: Actually, I found the problem; I'm using Python 3.0. I'll try this with the newest Python version.

Comment: @Wai-man, You can use `end.lower() == "end"' or `end.upper() == "END"`

Answer (score 4):

The condition is wrong -

```
if end == ("end") and ("End"):
```

This would only evaluate to true (when end is `'end'` ), because this would get translated as -

```
if ((end == "end") and "End")
```

And any non-empty string in python is True-like (has true value in boolean context.)

To check for all cases, best thing to do would be to check your variable's `.lower()` with `'end'` , example -

```
if end is not None and end.lower() == "end":
```

And since you are taking input using `input()` function, you actually do not need the `is not None` part, so you can do -

```
if end.lower() == "end":
```